# PDF Open Office or MS Word

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word

I am new to java, I have to read a PDF, Open Office or MS Word file and make changes in the file and render as PDF document on my web page. Please someone tell me which of these file's API or SDK is easy to use and also tell me best SDK for this. So I can read, Update and render easily. file also contains Table but there is no image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to read Microsoft Office files. There are many libraries for PDF in Java. [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) is something I have used. Once you pick the tools, do a selective search on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). There are plenty of discussions around these tools.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the types of updates you are doing, modifying PDF is going to be a problem - it's not intended for editing.  You might have to find some way of converting the PDF to something first, then edit.  Depending on the types of changes you want to make and the documents you are working from even editing DOC and Writer files is going to be tricky.  They are all different formats.
As Jayan mentioned, iText and POI may help you a little.  OpenOffice Writer documents can be edited by unzipping then modifying the XML or using the UNO API.  Word documents can be editied by using MS Office automation (bad idea), converting to OpenOffice first then editing, or if DOCX, unzipping and processing the XML.

Good luck.